# Setting local storage from dynamically created textarea's values'

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, dynamically-generated

I am creating a work day calendar application for a school project where the user can save notes that will remain on the screen after the window is refreshed. I dynamically added text area and button elements with corresponding id's (among some other elements) for the typical 9am-5pm hours like so:

```
for (let i = 9; i <= 17; i++) {
  let textAreaEl = $('<textarea>')
    .addClass('description col-8 col-md-10')
    .attr('id', 'note-' + i)
    .attr('rows', '3');
  let saveBtnEl = $('<button>')
    .addClass('btn saveBtn col-2 col-md-1')
    .attr('aria-label', 'save-' + i);
}
```

Now I am using the setItem and getItem methods of local storage to store and retrieve the value of the textareas. I can properly save specific text area values with their corresponding save buttons, but I can only save one. Also, when I refresh the page the getItem method is setting the value of the one stored value to every textarea element. Here is the localStorage code:

```
let savedNote = localStorage.getItem('savedNote');
if (savedNote !== null) {
  $('.description').val(savedNote);
    console.log(savedNote);
}

$('.saveBtn').on('click', function () {
  let note = $(this).prev('.description').val();
  localStorage.setItem('savedNote', note); 
    
});
```

[The localStorage after clicking the sibling button of the text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy7p4.png)

[The application after refreshing the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1psi.png)

I sort of have an understanding of why I can only save one element and why every textarea value is being filled after the refresh, I have only created one savedNote value which is storing values based on the element previous to the button clicked. Then when I use getItem it is providing values to the textarea element based on the class which will indeed change all values. I'm stuck trying to figure out how I could create a loop that iterates through the textarea elements based on their id's (as they are given id's like such: id="note-9", id="note-10" etc...). Hopefully this makes sense, I am a little new to JS and JQuery.

Comment: Put all the notes in a JSON array. When you fetch the JSON, loop through the array and update the value of the corresponding textarea.

Comment: Your loop will keep on iterating and only the last iteration will take effect thus **all** your `textarea`s and `button`s will have the same `ID`s, classes and attributes(for example, your `textarea`s will all have the same `ID` which will be `note17` once the loop finishes). Also, I don't understand why you have a loop that adds some `ID`s/attributes which can be added directly in the `HTML`. For the `localStorage`, you could follow the suggestion by @Barmar and that should do the trick quite easily.

Comment: The `for` loop never appends the textareas and buttons to the DOM. Did you leave that out?

Comment: @Barmar assuming the OP meant to do so because I can't really get why using the loop that way which simply keeps on overwriting.

Comment: @Barmar I left the appends out to keep the post a little shorter, so would creating that JSON array look something like this: let note = [ { note: note } ] ?

Comment: @ths using the for loop to dynamically create elements and append them was more of a suggestion from the instructor for practice. Sorry if I made the post a little confusing by leaving the rest of the loop out. But the elements were created with the correct id's and such.

Comment: @ths What do you think it's overwriting? That code *creates* elements, it doesn't overwrite anything. That's why it's clear that the appends were omitted. I think you're misreading it as `$("textarea")` rather than `$("<textarea>")`

Comment: @Barmar yep! didn't see that at first and omitting the lines that append the elements to the `HTML` made me miss those `<>`. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @joreland you can store a json where you have the `textarea`s `ID`s as keys and their corresponding texts as values. Pretty much the same as what Barmar mentioned already.